# How can I design Ember deleteRecord method without Ember data?

Tags: ember.js, model, controller, destroy

My Ember version:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- 
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.0 
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0 
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.0 
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

I design my model like this:

```
App.Product = Em.Object.extend
  isNew: (->
    not @get('id')
  ).property('id')

  save: ->
    if @get('isNew')
      url = "/api/products.json"
      method = 'POST'
    else
      url = "/api/products/#{@get('id')}.json"
      method = 'PATCH'

    $.ajax(url: url, type: method, data: @paramsForSave()).then(
      (payload) =>
        @setProperties(payload.product)
      (xhr) =>
        xhr.responseJSON.errors
    )

  deleteRecord: ->
    $.ajax(url: "/api/products/#{@get('id')}.json", type: "DELETE").then (payload) =>
      @destroy

  paramsForSave: ->
    keys = ['name']
    params = @getProperties(keys)
    params[key] = null for key in params when params[key] == undefined

    {product: params}

App.Product.reopenClass
  _findAll: (params) ->
    modelClass = @
    $.get("/api/products.json", params).then (payload)->
      payload.products.map (obj)-> 
        modelClass.create(obj)

  findAll: (params) ->
    RepairFacility.PromiseArray.create promise: @_findAll(params)

  _find: (id)->
    modelClass = @
    $.get("/api/products/#{id}.json").then (obj) ->
      modelClass.create(obj.product)

  find: (id) ->
    RepairFacility.PromiseObject.create promise: @_find(id)
```

The model to be working normally. But when I use `deleteRecord` to destroy my model, if I could not `transitionToRoute`, the model is destroyed in the database but also here in the page.
**The problem is how can I remove this model from my arrary controller or object controller?**

Example:

```
Model Order has many Product
```

So I want to remove Product in the Order 'show' page. The Order 'show' page:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <section class="widget">
      <header>
        <h4>
          Number: {{number}}
        </h4>
      </header>
      <div class="body">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {{#each products itemController='product'}}
              <tr>
                <td>{{name}}</td>
                <td>
                  <a href="#" {{action "destroy"}} class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
                    {{fa-icon 'trash-o'}}
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
            {{/each}}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

And `ProductController` is:

```
App.ProductController = Em.ObjectController.extend
  needs: ['order']

  init: ->
    @set("product", App.Product.create(@content))

  actions: 
    destroy: ->
      if confirm("Are you sure?")
        @product.deleteRecord().then ()=>
          @destroy
```

I try to use `removeObject`, `remove`. All of this could not work. The data is remove from the database, but the product also in the front page.

The problem is my model design all the other?
Thank you!

Comment: You've tagged this `ember-data` but it doesn't look like you're using it. Is that correct?

Comment: @claptimes Oh.Sorry. I had been edited it.